# Soft Delete on Entity Framework Many-to-Many Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a many to many EF map similar to the example below. I am using EF code first approach so my mapping class inherits EntityTypeConfiguration<>.

```
this.HasMany(a => a.KPIs)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(a =>
            {
                a.ToTable("KeyResultArea_KeyPerformanceIndicator_Mapping");
                a.MapLeftKey("KRA_Id");
                a.MapRightKey("KPI_Id");
            });
```

As a result of this im left with the schema shown below.

[image]

No great surprises so far. - However I would like to be able to soft delete one of these mappings so my **desired schema** would look something like this;

```
dbo.KeyResultArea_KeyPerformanceIndicator_Mapping(
   KRA_Id int,
   KPI_Id int,
   Deleted bit)
```

Hope it makes sense, any pointers would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may need to have your own logic to define the deletion of the relationships. You can define new enttity type for the relationship,

```
public class KRAKPI{

public int KPA_Id{get;set;}
public int KRA_Id{get;set;}
public bool IsDeleted{get;set;}

}
```

And then you can define the deletion logic in save changes by getting all `KRAKPI` deleted items in the state manager and setting them to modified state with changing the `IsDeleted` value.
[Here is a post](http://blog.jorgef.net/2010/12/ef-soft-delete.html) on setting the deleted value in save changes method.

Comment: Yeah this is the only way ive found to do this

Comment: hmmm ok, so just to I understand and so I can map this. The domain model relationship would look something like KRA.KRAKPI.KPIs.FirstOrDefault().Name where previously I had KRA.KPIs.FirstOrDefault().Name? Thanks for your reply